# Jzy3d 3d interpolation plots not rendering

Tags: plot, graph, interpolation, jzy3d

I am trying to plot a 3d path given a set of coordinates. From jzy3d's demo application, I've found that this is possible through their `BernsteinInterpolator` and `LineStripInterpolated` classes.

With the help of their source code, my attempt to reproduce this is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BernsteinInterpolator interp = new BernsteinInterpolator();

    List<Coord3d> controlCoords = new ArrayList<>();
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));        
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(1.0, 0.0, 2.0));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(1.0, 1.0, 2.0));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(0.0, 1.0, 2.0));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(3.0, 2.0, -1.0));

    LineStripInterpolated line = new LineStripInterpolated(interp, controlCoords, 30);

    Chart chart = new AWTChart(Quality.Intermediate);
    chart.add(line);
    chart.open("chart test", 600, 600);
}
```

This is what I would expect to get, according to the demo application -> [DemoPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0mge.png)

Unfortunately, the above only renders a blank window with no errors or exceptions. Does anyone have any idea what went wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I digged a little deeper into the source code and found that there is a way to bypass the `LineStripInterpolated` class as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Coord3d> controlCoords = new ArrayList<>();
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(1.0F, 0.0F, 2.0F));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(1.0F, 1.0F, 2.0F));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(0.0F, 1.0F, 2.0F));
    controlCoords.add(new Coord3d(3.0F, 2.0F, -1.0F));

    BernsteinInterpolator interp = new BernsteinInterpolator();
    List<Coord3d> interpolatedCoords = interp.interpolate(controlCoords, 30);

    List<Point> controlPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Coord3d coord : controlCoords) {
        controlPoints.add(new Point(coord, Color.RED, 5.0));
    }

    List<Point> interpPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Coord3d coord : interpolatedCoords) {
        interpPoints.add(new Point(coord, Color.BLUE, 3.0));
    }

    LineStrip line = new LineStrip(interpolatedCoords);
    line.setWireframeColor(Color.BLACK);

    Chart chart = new AWTChart(Quality.Intermediate);
    chart.add(line);
    chart.add(controlPoints);
    chart.add(interpPoints);
    chart.open("chart test", 600, 600);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem. I'm still curious as to why my previous method didn't work though. :(